# How to print a specific range of lines and enumerate them with sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed, printf, cat

I would like to know how to print specific range of lines using sed or awk and enumerate them like something like this

```
HORSE
CAT
DOG
LION
MOUSE
MONKEY
SNAKE
PANDA
WOLF
TIGER
```

so that the output of the line 4-9 looks like this

```
1. LION
2. MOUSE
3. MONKEY
4. SNAKE
5. PANDA
6. WOLF
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat youdatafile | awk '(NR>=4 && NR<=9) {print($0)}'| awk '{print(NR ". " $0)}'
```

or shortly

```
awk 'BEGIN {n=1} (NR>=4 && NR<=9) {print(n ". " $0); n++}' yourdatafile
```

Answer (score 1):

Using keywords in the range:

```
$ awk '/LION/,/WOLF/{print ++c,$0}' file
```

Output:

```
1 LION
2 MOUSE
3 MONKEY
4 SNAKE
5 PANDA
6 WOLF
```

Or using record numbers:

```
$ awk 'NR==4,NR==9{print ++c,$0}' file
```